# Building OpenCV 3.0.0's DLLs for Visual Studio 2015 with Cmake

Tags: c++, opencv, dll, cmake, visual-studio-2015

Following the instructions here:

docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_Opencv/windows_visual_studio_Opencv.html#windows-visual-studio-how-to

I setup an OpenCV project in VS 2015 Community and used the pre-built libraries. It works until I get this message:

"MSVCP120D.dll is missing from your computer"

From doing some searching I gathered this means that the pre-build libraries are only supposed to be used with an older version of VS so I figured I'd just compile them myself using this:

docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html#windowssetpathandenviromentvariablehere

While it appears to compile properly and despite flagging "BUILD_SHARED_LIBS" I can't find any DLL files in the output - just a lot of VS solutions:

imgur.com/JdSc5CH

Would someone be able to give me some advice on how to generate the DLLs?

thanks!

Comment: You need to build those solutions! Open OpenCV.sln, build solution and then build Install project, both debug and relase

Comment: your libs will be under "install" folder then

Comment: Ah, working now - thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'm a beginner at this stuff.  I've since learned a lot about Visual Studio, about CMake and about OpenCV. Got it all working now, took me a day or two.

It turns out you have to compile the openCV library from git repository in order to be compatible with Visual Studio (VS14) 2015.  As of this date, no go on pre-compiled version supporting VS14.

I've organized what I've learned, placed it [online here](http://dogfeatherdesign.com/opencv-3-0-microsoft-visual-studio-2015-cmake-and-c/) in case anybody else has the same frustrations. Its pretty detailed, too much content to post here.

Answer (score 0):

VS2015 uses MSVCP140.dll, I think your error message is about a redistributable package of VS2013.

And try BUILD_SHARED_LIBS as on/off.